# How to return JsonArray in a Java Response object

Tags: java, json, web-services

I'm trying to implement java based web-service server which returns to Json  and java script based web-service client. Here is my java part :

```
@Path("/myapp")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyRecommender {
            @POST
            @Path("/recs")
            public Response getRecommendations() {
                //Assume recommendation List contains some Recommendation objects 
                //I removed it for simplicity.            
                List<Recommendation> recommendation;
                JsonArrayBuilder builder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
                for (Recommendation rec : recommendations) {
                    builder.add(Json.createObjectBuilder().add("firstPersonName", "\"" + rec.getFirstPerson().getName() + "\"")
                            .add("firsPersonURL", "\"" + rec.getFirstPerson().getURL() + "\"")
                            .add("secondPersonName", "\"" + rec.getSecondPerson().getName() + "\"")
                            .add("secondPersonURL", "\"" + rec.getSecondPerson().getURL() + "\"")
                            .add("score", "\"" + rec.getSimilarity() + "\""));
                }
                JsonArray jsonData = builder.build();
                return Response.ok(jsonData, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST").allow("OPTIONS").build();
            }
        }
}
```

Now, when I call this function from my js client, I got :

```
POST http://localhost:8080/myapp/recs 500 (Request failed.)
```

But when I replace the for loop and return with the following code snipped I got response in my js correctly.

Changed part :

```
// remove for loop and change jsonData type.
  String jsonData = "{\"name\":\"John\"}";
  return Response.ok(jsonData, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
          .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST").allow("OPTIONS").build();
```

So, I wonder what might be problem ? Since its my first time with web-services, I have some difficulty to debug my code.

**EDIT**

By the way, I get also another error when I try to first version of getRecommendations() functions(with loop)

```
     XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/myapp/recs. 
     No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.   
    Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

But as I said, When I remove the loop and put second code snipped into getRecommendations() functions, both of the errors are gone and I get the response in my website.

**EDIT2**

When I changed the loop and return statement of getRecommendations() function with the below I again **get** the same errors

```
 JsonObject value = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("name", "John").build();
return Response.ok(value, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
              .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST").allow("OPTIONS").build();
```

**EDIT 3**

As far as I understood, `createObjectBuilder().build()` or `JsonArrayBuilder.build()` return an  `JSON object` and below of this build statement in my getRecommendations() function is not even run. So, I think my problem how could I give Access-Control-Allow-Origin permission to this object?

Comment: HTTP 500 is an internal server error. did you check if the server is connected and working properly?

Comment: @SudiptoChandra yea, as I said, if I replaced the loop and return statement of my getRecommendations() function with the second code snipped, It works properly. Therefore I dont think there could be any connection problem.

Comment: IMHO `getRecommendations()` should be annotated with `@GET`

Comment: @PeterMmm may I ask why do you think in that way ?

Comment: Prefixing & suffixing with " doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @KDM If it was wrong, I think I could not get the response with the second version of my getRecommendations() function(without loop and changing return type with the second code snippet)

Comment: @PeterMmm I changed POST to GET in both server and client side but still got the same errors.

Comment: @KDM Thank you, I made mistake while  copying my function to here. I corrected it.

Comment: In the second version, the " are required because you are converting a string to Jason object. I expect the build.add to take care of it. I might be wrong, but you can just check whether it makes a difference.

Comment: @KDM I copied it from here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html .According to it, my way does not look like wrong?

Comment: Hmm... Had a look at it, I am sure now that prefixing & suffixing is wrong. Typing on an iPad is a pain, I can give a better explanation later. Just try it. If you have validations on url/similarity etc. they might fail, because they get extra ".

Comment: @KDM I understand your point now, I editted my question (edit2) could you please loot it ?

Comment: Can you print value.tostring & see what it shows?

Comment: @KDM suprisingly it did not print anything. Is it normal?

Comment: @KDM I think I have a problem with .build() function. Whenever I use it in getRecommendations() function I gets the errors I mention above. Even if I use it in the edit2 way. (without returning it)

Answer (score 2):

If it is ok to use a third Party Library, using Google's Gson could be an efficient solution in this case. When converting Models to JSON it is quite handy.
What you can do is something like this.

`ArrayList<Recommendation> recommendationList = new ArrayList<Recommendation>();

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonData = gson.toJson(reccomendationList);`

To use it as a dependency in your POM file you could do this.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try simplest approach:

```
return Response.ok().entity(recommendation).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST").allow("OPTIONS").build();
```

Comment: When I try your solution I get the same errors too.

Comment: Are you sure that `recommendation!=null` ? In any case you can wrap method body inside try{}catch() and print stacktrace.

Comment: I'm sure because I also print out content of recommendation into console. (I removed it in the question for the sake of simplicity)